# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #3

Tags: visual, rebus

This puzzle suggests either an actor or a character from the original Twilight Zone. Last one for today.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Andy Marshak from the episode *The Four of Us Are Dying*

Because

> Andy [Garcia] + Mars + shack